Passing date value to HTML form in django framework
I am building my first application with Django. I am trying to make a template form to update values in a row in  a table in a database. I want to populate all the forms fields with the existing values from the database. I can pass dates in as text just fine:
This displays my date:
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ table.date }}">

but when I try the same value into a date field, it remains blank with I render
This displays a blank date field:
<input type="date" class="form-control" value="{{ table.date }}">

I assume this has to do with handling date formatting. Is there an easy way to handle this in the html? or does it require backend work?
Any python code I tried to write into the template resulted in a 404. Still learning what the capabilities are. From what I have read I am guessing correct way to do this is with a function in my model, but I was hoping I could write something to convert the date in my template.
My view is basic:
def update(request, id):
    table = table.objects.get(pk=id)
    return render(request, 'app/tempate.html', {'table' : table})


Check the HTML element in Inspect Element. See if there is any kind of data in the value field or if it is just empty.

What does table.date look like? provide an example value.

oh, didn't think about inspecting the element. It does have a value: June 21, 2024, but still not displaying.

I don't recall the format I originally inputted the date in. whatever the Django API requires. When the date renders as text it is in this format: June 21, 2024

If I change the value to yyyy-mm-dd formatting in the inspector is displays just fine. So I guess that's confirms it is a date formatting issue.

It is a formatting issue as you guessed in your comments. The best approach is to make use of the built-in date template tag provided by the framework to manipulate the value, instead of doing it in the view:
<input type="date" class="form-control" value="{{ date|date:'Y-m-d' }}">


Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.
